# Обновление контента

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть цель: добавилась новость, надо чтобы она у юзера подгрузилась, кроме ajax с таймером на проверку через интервал есть способы? Что-то вроде событий...

Вопрос №2: сайт состоит из одной страницы (для юзеров), к которой передаются параметры, что отображать. В зависимости от нужд вызывается функция из php файла с функциями, для ajax - что лучше? Обращаться ajax-ом через параметры к этому файлу или всё-таки сделать разбивку по файлам в плане: Действие-ОтдельныйФайл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Как по мне, то аякс с таймером - самый лучший вариант решения. События тут нельзя использовать, т.к. нет постоянного соединения с сервером. Т.е. с клиента все-равно нужно отправлять запрос.

Конечно, если поискать, то есть другие варианты решения, например [PHP Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), но использовать их для обновления новостей...

Вот [отличная статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/41223/), какраз на вашу тему.

2.В один файл.

Comment: Спасибо, полный ответ, большое спасибо